# Single machine scheduling with deadlines

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am looking for the good algorithm for solving a permutation of the jobs such that if the jobs are processed in that order, then each job finishes by its deadline.
Set `{j1,j2, ... , jn}` of `n` jobs and processing times `t` and deadlines `d` for each job are given. Could you recommend any possible algorithm?

Comment: Is this a CS assignment? If so you should ask your tutors for help. But anyway first intuition is greedy, start with the job that has the latest deadline. Schedule it such that it will finish at the deadline. Same for the second latest job, but also such that it doesn't overlap with previously scheduled job. If you can't schedule a job, there is no schedule for the problem. Complexity should be n log n because of the sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal scheduling algorithm in your case is the earliest-deadline-first([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling)). So you sort the jobs by the deadline and start from the earliest to the farthest. It has been proven that if there exists a feasible schedule with no deadline violations, EDF finds it.

In case that your jobs have priorities (weights), a similar algorithm follows. See Maximum Profit Scheduling ([MPS](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~peter/teachingPortfolio/COMP3600lect20.pdf)).

Here is the implementation of MPS: [MPS C++ Code](https://code.google.com/p/ulib/source/browse/trunk/src/ext1/dyn_prg/dp_mps.c).

Comment: what do you mean sort by deadline they are already sorted by arrival time??